# How do you scale cloth simulations?

Tags: cloth-simulation, scale

I can't figure out what exactly to do with this, when I run the simulation at a smaller scale, everything is fine.

[image]

When I scale it by 10 it becomes strange, even though everything is aligned with the origin and the force field is a point and as such scale shouldn't affect it.

[image]

Which parameters need to be modified for it to scale correctly?

Comment: Have you tried just scaling it *then* baking?

Comment: I haven't been baking anything. Should I be baking things? I've been just scaling and pressing spacebar and being disappointed at the results.

Comment: You do need to bake it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your simulation to work efficiently, you must first, save your .blend file, then **bake** the simulation. The bake settings are under the cache tab in the cloth settings. You will be able to scale it to whatever then.